# How to write a basic org-babel-execute function for a new language?

Tags: org-babel

What I'm trying to achieve is very simple: take a source block, write it to a temp file, pass the file name as an argument to an executable which will run it, and then include the output in the `#RESULTS` block. The snippet below seems close, but when I try to execute the code block the executable (`nim`) complains that it expected a file name so I guess it passes the block body via `stdin` instead of temp file:

```el
(defun org-babel-execute:nim (body params)
 "Execute a block of Nim code with org-babel."
 (message "executing Nim source code block")
    (org-babel-eval "nim r " body))
```

Second attempt, based on @NickD's comment and `org-babel-execute:dot`:

```el
  (defun org-babel-execute:nim (body params)
    "Execute a block of Nim code with org-babel."
    (message "executing Nim source code block")
    (let* (in-file (org-babel-temp-file "nim-")))
    (with-temp-file in-file
      (insert body))
    (org-babel-eval (format "nim r %s" (org-babel-process-file-name in-file))))
```

When trying to execute a code block, getting "Symbol's value as variable is void: in-file"

Comment: Your guess may be correct. As one example, check out [`org-babel-execute:dot`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/ob-dot.el#L64) which does something very similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks @NickD, tried cobbling something together based on that but getting a differetn error; I updated the question

Comment: The `let*` is wrong, it doesn't bind `in-file` to anything and the following code should be in its body instead. This is absolutely not Org's fault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to define `org-babel-execute:nim`:

```lisp
(defun org-babel-execute:nim (body params)
  "Execute a block of Nim code with org-babel."
```

While we *could* use `nim` via STDIN, it will clutter the current working directory. Therefore, let us use a temporary file instead. `nim` also needs files to start with a letter and end with `.nim`, so we adjust the arguments to `org-babel-temp-file`. For some less noise, let's also change the default verbosity, but make it adjustable:

```lisp
(let ((in-file (org-babel-temp-file "n" ".nim"))
      (verbosity (or (cdr (assq :verbosity params)) 0)))
  (with-temp-file in-file
    (insert body))
```

Last but not least, we call `org-babel-eval`. Since we supplied the original `body` in our `in-file`, we can keep the `body` argument of `org-babel-eval` empty. One could probably also change the working directory to a temporary directory instead, but I'm not familiar with `nim`, at all.

```lisp
(org-babel-eval
 (format "nim compile --verbosity=%d --run %s" verbosity
         (org-babel-process-file-name in-file))
 "")))
```

Here's all at once:

```lisp
(defun org-babel-execute:nim (body params)
  "Execute a block of Nim code with org-babel."
  (let ((in-file (org-babel-temp-file "n" ".nim"))
        (verbosity (or (cdr (assq :verbosity params)) 0)))
    (with-temp-file in-file
      (insert body))
    (org-babel-eval
     (format "nim compile --verbosity=%d --run %s" verbosity
             (org-babel-process-file-name in-file))
     "")))
```

And here's an example:

```lisp
#+begin_src nim
var name : string = "Woof"
echo "Hi, ", name, "!"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hi, Woof!
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.